# Does Python's time.time() return a timestamp in UTC?

Tags: python, time, utc

I need to generate a UNIX timestamp in UTC time so I'm using `time.time()` to produce it.
Do I need to do anything else or is the timestamp automatically in UTC?

Answer (score 24):

Technically, [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) doesn't specify, and practically, at least in CPython, it returns a timestamp in whatever format is used by the underlying standard C library's `time` function.

The C standard (which isn't freely available) doesn't say whether this is GMT, and neither does the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html). It just says:

> The `time()` function shall return the value of time in seconds since the Epoch.

… without saying anything about timezone, except that you can pass it to `localtime` or `gmtime` to get a "broken-down time" in local or GMT timezones.

So, this is platform-specific. A platform can return anything it wants for `time`, as long as it does so in a way that makes `localtime` and `gmtime` work properly.

That being said, it's *usually* going to be GMT—or, rather, either UTC (Windows), or UTC-except-for-leap-seconds (most other platforms). For example, [FreeBSD](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/time.3.html) says:

> The `time()` function returns the value of time in seconds since 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal Time, without including leap seconds.

OS X and most other *BSDs have the same manpage, [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [linux/glibc](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) also specifically return UTC (with or without leap seconds), etc.

Also, the Python documentation says:

> To find out what the epoch is, look at `gmtime(0)`.

Putting that together with the definitions for `time` and `gmtime`, it would be much more work for a platform to return local timestamps than GMT. (That being said, this statement can't be all that authoritative, because it's actually not quite true for any POSIX platform, thanks to leap seconds.)

Comment: So then, Windows returns a UTC adjusted for leap seconds, while most other systems will return a more monotonic value, not having accounted for leap seconds, and therefore different from the UTC returned by a windows based python install?

Answer (score 10):

`time.time()` returns seconds [since epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so it doesn't define which time standard or zone is being used.

Convert to time standards using:

- [`time.localtime([secs])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) - Local time as defined by your operating system
- [`time.gmtime([secs])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) - UTC

They both return a [`time.struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

```
>>> t = time.time()
>>> time.localtime(t)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=15, tm_hour=2, tm_min=41, tm_sec=49, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=135, tm_isdst=1)
>>> time.gmtime(t)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=15, tm_hour=0, tm_min=41, tm_sec=49, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=135, tm_isdst=0)
```