# Get timestamps with the same time_zone from all nodes in distributed system with Python

Tags: python, python-datetime, distributed-system

I am building a mechanism to store information with the timestamp in a distributed system. Assuming that the information from all nodes in a distributed system will be merged together and sorted according to timestamp, how to make sure that all the timestamps from all systems refer to the same time_zone in Python?

From my research, `time.time()` returns the time since `Epoch`, but it might return different results depending on the platform:

[Does Python's time.time() return a timestamp in UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554887/does-pythons-time-time-return-a-timestamp-in-utc)

Another solution that comes to my mind is to use `datetime.utcnow()` from `datetime` package. If I use `datetime.utcnow()` in all nodes, from my understanding all nodes will be using the same time_zone (UTC), hence the timestamps between all the nodes will be in sync. Can anyone confirm if I am correct in my logic?

Comment: I can confirm that `utcnow()`  returns the correct (*naive*) utc value when run on my PDT aware computer. The docs warn that you should use an aware object regardless - `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want synchronize data with time, System time is not good idea for distributed systems. In distributed systems, system time is unreliable. There are many different scenarios where a simple failure. Example scenarios:

- Someone can change local time on machine(or accidentally)
- Out-of-date machine joining a cluster
- synchronized clocks drifting at slightly different rates

That can cause not-traceable anomalies. [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) can help to you. You can synchronize times with this protocol. These strategies named Global Clock. It is not easy for implement and increase latency.

As far as I know [Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/index.html) is using NTP for synchronize data.