# Problem with time.time() between functions in Python

Tags: python, time

I am running this program on ubuntu with Python 3.10.12. I need to measure the time used to evaluate a probability function. This is the code.

```py
def likelihood(x, fun):
    if fun == 0:
        rosenbrock(x)
    else:
        rosenbrock_simplified(x)


def rosenbrock(x):
    for i in range(3000):
        # some calculation
    return logl

def time_evaluation():
   
    x = np.random.normal(size=2)
    start = time.time()
    value = likelihood(x, 0)
    stop = time.time()

    return stop - start
```

Running this code I obtain little time values. if i run this code measuring the time inside the function `rosenbrock` the values are higher. Is it possible that time.time() measure only the time needed for likelihood function call?

as I said before I noticed this discrepancy of times by moving `time.time()` within the `rosenbrock` function.

Comment: welcome to the community! First, it helps to answer your question more accurately if you provide a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Second, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_time.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554887/does-pythons-time-time-return-a-timestamp-in-utc) provide some background on how `time.time()` works. It appears that it can differ per system which time is returned.

Comment: Have to run the experiments multiple times with the same discrepancy? Sometimes CPU is used by another unrelated task . Also I would use `time.perf_counter()`

Comment: Have you considered using the timeit module instead? See this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579357/time-time-vs-timeit-timeit

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I tried the code multiple times on the same CPU, measuring the time inside `rosenbrock` function I obteined almost 1 second, measuring the time of `likelihood` I obtained 0.000002. I think that is strange, maybe `time.time()` measure only the `likelihood` call time.

Comment: Something is off. I am not sure to properly help. Can you change the time_evaluation to a decorator and then let’s decorate the function?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. In order for us to reproduce your problem, we also need to know how you measured the time inside the function `rosenbrock `.

Answer (score 0):

These time differences might be due to the short time it takes to run your code. There will always be some fluctuations in this case.

You should run your function e.g. 1000 times (or more/less, it should run for a few minutes at least in any case and there should be no less than 10-20 calls), measure the time necessary to complete all 1000 calls and then divide the time by the number of calls to obtain the time of one call.

Comment: I have evaluated the median of five run. with the code in wich I measure the time inside 'rosenbrock' function I obtain almost 1 second, with the code posted 0.000002 second. cannot be a problem of 'time.time()', where it only measures the time of 'likelihood' call?

Comment: @NicolòMolteni As I've said, you should do something like this 
`start = time.time()

for i in range(500000): 

    value = likelihood(x, 0)

stop = time.time()

print(stop-start)`